# Blackberry Simulator

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, blackberry, emulator

I just downloaded the Blackberry Simulator from one of [RIM's download pages](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp). I went ahead and downloaded a generic simulator for the Curve 9900 running on OS 7.1 (ver 7.1.0.137). When I fired the setup file up, I got the following message:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows 
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether 
>   you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then 
>   contact the software publisher.

I am running a 64-bit machine, so does anyone know where one can get a 64-bit version of the simulator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like a [known issue](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29188/Known_issues_1498087_11.jsp)

> When you start the BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator in Windows 7
>   64-bit, the simulator might not run. (1149499)
>
> Impact: You cannot use the simulator.
>
> Workaround: None.

Comment: Wow, what a useful KB entry that is.

Answer (score 2):

I saw something similar to this recently, and it turns out the installer wasn't 64-bit ready, even though the software inside didn't care.  Perhaps try extracting the files from within the EXE installer (using something like 7-zip) and see if you can install from the extracted files.